# Signup JSP Page has error on displaying errors

Tags: javascript, jsp

Below is my Signup.jsp. If i type the valid form inputs its working fine. If i input wrong values then its showing errors and when i again type some vlaue without refreshing the page and submit, and again if the same field has some other error then both the old error and new error are getting displayed.

**for ex: if at the first time i dont enter any first name then it will display an error *Please provide your first name.and if i again give some wrong value to the same field both *Please provide your first name. and *Please provide a valid first name. are getting displayed.**

**And when i **reset*** these errors still getting displayed. How to reset the whole page using RESET Button*

```
<form action="RegisterServlet" method="post" name="Register" onSubmit="return validate()">
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtFname" id="fname" maxlength="30" onKeyup="capitalize(this)"/><br/>
<span  id="errorFirstNameMissing" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your first name.</font></span>
<span  id="errorFirstNameInValid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid first name.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtLname" id="lname" maxlength="30" onKeyup="capitalize(this)"/><br/>
<span id="errorLastNameMissing" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your Last name.</font></span>
<span id="errorLastNameInValid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid Last name.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender* : </td>
<td><select name = "txtGender" id="gender">
<option value="unknown">Select your Gender</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select><br/>
<span id="errorMissingGender" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please select a Gender.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category* : </td>
<td><select name = "txtCategory" id="category">
<option value="unknown">Select your Category</option>
<option value="Affiliate">Affiliate</option>
<option value="Client">Client</option>
<option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</select><br/>
<span id="errorMissingCategory" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please select a Category.</font></span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><script type="text/javascript"
src="js/Calendar.js"></script>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Age :</td>
<td><input type=text name=txtAge id="ageId" readonly  style="width: 20px;background-color:#D0D0D0;border:none"/>yrs.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address* : </td>
<td><textarea rows="5" name="txtAddr" id="addr" cols="30"></textarea><br/>
<span id="errorMissingAddress" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid Address.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State* :</td>  
<td> <select onchange="print_city('city',this.selectedIndex);" id="state" name ="txtState"></select><br/>
<span id="errorMissingState" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please select a state.</font></span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City* :</td> <td><select name ="txtCity" id ="city"></select>
        <script language="javascript">print_state("state");</script><br/>
<span id="errorMissingCity" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please select a city.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pincode* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtPin" id="pin"/><br/>
<span id="errorMissingPinCode" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your Pincode.</font></span>
<span id="errorPinCodeInvalid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid Pincode.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>e-Mail* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="email"/><br/>
<span id="errorMissingEmail" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your emailId.</font></span>
<span id="errorEmailInvalid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid emailId.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact Number : </td>
<td><input type="text"  name="txtStd" id="std" maxlength="6" style="width: 40px"/>-<input type="text" name="txtPhone" id="phone" maxlength="8"/><br/>
<span id="errorStdCodeInvalid" style="visibility:hidden;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid std code.</font></span>
<span id="errorPhoneNoInvalid" style="visibility:hidden;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid contact no.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Mobile Number* : </td>
<td>+91-<input type="text" name="txtMobile" id="mobile" maxlength="10"/><br/>
<span id="errorMissingMobileNo" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your mobile number.</font></span>
<span id="errorMobileNoInvalid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid mobile number.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<p><font color="red">Note: All the fields marked with * are mandatory.</font></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="chkAgree" onclick="EnableSubmit(this)" /><font color="green"> I here by declare that the above data entered by me is true to my knowledge.</font> </p>
<br/>

<div class="style2">
<table>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" id="submit" disabled style="width: 80px;height: 40px">Submit</button></td>
<td><div class="divider"></div></td>
<td><button type="reset" style="width: 80px;height: 40px">Reset</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

**Below is my code for validate() in javascript**

```
        function validate(){
var valid = true;
var validationMessage = 'Please correct the following errors:\r\n';
var regex=/^([A-Za-z]{3,30}$)/;
var lregex=/^([A-Za-z]{1,30}$)/;
var pinRegex=/^[0-9]{0,6}$/;
var emailRegex=/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
var stdRegex=/^[0-9]{0,6}$/;
var phoneRegex=/^[0-9]{0,8}$/;
var mobileRegex=/^[0-9]{10}$/;
var dateRegex=/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;



if (document.getElementById('fname').value.length == 0) {
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - First name is missing\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.display='';
valid = false;
}
else if(!regex.test(document.getElementById('fname').value)){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - First name is not valid can contain only letters from A-z and a-z\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.display='none';
}



if (document.getElementById('lname').value.length == 0){
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Last name is missing\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorLastNameMissing').style.display='';
valid = false;
}
else if(!lregex.test(document.getElementById('lname').value)){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Last name is not valid can contain only letters from A-z and a-z\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorLastNameInValid').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorLastNameMissing').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('errorLastNameInValid').style.display='none';
}

if (document.getElementById('gender').value == 'unknown'){
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Please select a gender\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorMissingGender').style.display='';
valid = false;
}
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingGender').style.display='none';
    }

if (document.getElementById('category').value == 'unknown'){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Please select a category\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingCategory').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingCategory').style.display='none';
    }

if ((document.getElementById('SnapHost_Calendar').value.length == 0)){
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Date of Birth is missing\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorMissingDOB').style.display='';
valid = false;
}
else if(!dateRegex.test(document.getElementById('SnapHost_Calendar').value)){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Date is not valid should be in the format mm/dd/yyyy\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorDateInvalid').style.display='';
    valid = false;
}
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingDOB').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('errorDateInvalid').style.display='none';
    }

if (document.getElementById('addr').value.length == 0){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Address is missing\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingAddress').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingAddress').style.display='none';
    }

if (document.getElementById('state').value == ''){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Please select a state\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingState').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingState').style.display='none';
    }


if (document.getElementById('city').value == ''){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Please select a city\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingCity').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingCity').style.display='none';
    }

if (document.getElementById('pin').value.length == 0){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Pin code is missing\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingPinCode').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else if(!pinRegex.test(document.getElementById('pin').value)){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Pin code is not valid can contain only digits from 0-9\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorPinCodeInvalid').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorMissingPinCode').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('errorPinCodeInvalid').style.display='none';
}


if (document.getElementById('email').value.length == 0){
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Email is missing\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorMissingEmail').style.display='';
valid = false;
}
else if(!emailRegex.test(document.getElementById('email').value)){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Email is not valid\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorEmailInvalid').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorMissingEmail').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('errorEmailInvalid').style.display='none';
}

if((document.getElementById('std').value.length!=null)&& !stdRegex.test(document.getElementById('std').value)){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - std code is not valid\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorStdCodeInvalid').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorStdCodeInvalid').style.display='none';
    }

if((document.getElementById('phone').value.length!=null)&& !phoneRegex.test(document.getElementById('phone').value)){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Phone Nummber is not valid can contain digits only from 0-9\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorPhoneNoInvalid').style.display='';

    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorPhoneNoInvalid').style.display='none';
    }

if (document.getElementById('mobile').value.length == 0){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  -Mobile number is missing\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingMobileNo').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else if(!mobileRegex.test(document.getElementById('mobile').value)){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Mobile Nummber is not valid can contain digits only from 0-9\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMobileNoInvalid').style.display='';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorMissingMobileNo').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('errorMobileNoInvalid').style.display='none';
}


if (valid == false){
alert(validationMessage);
}
return valid;
}
```

**Please some one help me fix this problem.**

Comment: Have you tried going to HTML 5 with its `required` attribute, and the associated HTML5 form validation attributes? This does not look like a reasonable JSP. You might want to look at the Jakarta Commons-Validator library too.  See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/.

Comment: You need to hide all error messages first on submitting and then validate and display error messages.

Comment: @Shiju K Babu am new to javascript can u explain me with the code?     Wont display:none do what you said??

Comment: @Eric Jablow but i heard it works fine only on firefox??

Comment: Yes, HTML 5 requires a reasonably modern browser.  Commons-validator works for all browsers; I used it on an Apache Struts project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
span  id="errorFirstNameMissing" style="display:none
span  id="errorFirstNameInValid" style="display:none
```

In jsp, you are not displaying error message on page load.

When, value not given,

```
document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.display='';
```

You are making it visible.

Now when invalid value, you are enabling its display:

```
document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.display='';
```

But you have not hidden the previous error message for missing value. Its still in display mode. That's why both messages are shown when there is no page refresh.

**SOLUTION:**

You can hide these messages every time you enter the validate function.

```
function validate(){
document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.display='none';
```

Thus, every time you enter the validate function, it will hide all error message and display only the appropriate one depending on the respective validation.

You can use the same approach in your reset function also,  to hide all error message on reset.

Comment: so if my understanding is correct all my else blocks in validate() should this style.display=none; right...

Comment: You have to make them hide if you want it to enter "else". But in the scenario you explained, "else" alone will not work fine. So, you need to hide it on entering the validate function also.

Comment: no i changed my code as u said but errors only stopped getting displayed.

Comment: what errors are you getting? Are you referring to any error in code or the validation error messages ?

Comment: oh as it wasnt working i edit it k the same code as i ve posted in the question only i added the below code in the beginning of the fuction 'document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.display=none;
document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.display=none;'

Comment: As chat page has some loading issues, i'm posting here. For reset, you can write another function and write the code to make display none in that function.

Comment: In reset button, use an onclick function    onclick="resetForm()"  You can write this function in javascript function.

Comment: and write 'document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').value='';
 document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').value='';' in the resetForm() function?? But its not resetting the error

Comment: Or can i redirect the form to Signup.jsp in resetForm() function??

Comment: u can write a function for reset button


in that


'document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.display='none'


this will remove the error message